# Firebase hosting restricted access

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Can we restrict access to website with firebase hosting to prevent search engine indexing? This would be helpful for dev/staging environments.

Something like AWS Amplify restricting access https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-control.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control whether a crawler indexes your site with the usual `robots.txt` instructions. Note that this file is not specific to Firebase Hosting, and commonly used to control if/what parts of a site bots crawl.

But aside from that, there is no way to control access to the files in Firebase Hosting; all files are world-readable.

See also:

- [Prevent Search Engine Indexing of Angular 5 Website - Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828630/prevent-search-engine-indexing-of-angular-5-website-firebase) for some examples of a `robots.txt`.
- [Can Firebase hosting restrict access to resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212004/can-firebase-hosting-restrict-access-to-resources)