# Can we restrict access to firebase hosted site to particular VPN enabled clients?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have hosted a website using firebase hosting. The website is public and anyone can access it who knows the URL. I would like to restrict the access to the site to the users who have a valid VPN connection on their laptop/desktop. Is it at all possible & what are the steps needed for this? Since I'm working in the backend, I'm exploring the frontend as part of one POC.

Comment: Why would you choose VPN instead of authenticating users in your site?

Comment: All data on Firebase Hosting is publicly accessible. There is no way to restrict access to a subset of users. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753812, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27213823, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61862424 and a few more from https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+restrict+access+to+firebase+hosting+site

Comment: This app's access to be restricted at the network level. The authentication is part of it but that is the next level. The POC requirements are quite weird to be very frank :-(